# querying Date in mongodb with borders included

Tags: mongodb

I'm evaluating the following query on my collection with fake data:

`db.test_result.find({"date": {$gte: ISODate("2021-07-27"), $lte: ISODate("2021-08-31")}}).count()`

And despite the fact that I use `$lte` it does not include the second date value. Is it a bug? If so then how do I make the query so that the left and right borders are included?

Here is what a fake json obj looks like:

```
{
    "nfl": "Some",
    "rStatus": false,
    "mac": "02:00:00:00:00:00",
    "date": "2021-07-27T12:17:57",
    "MDCode": "123132132123",
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the fake data to make this complete.

Comment: Yeah I've just posted a typical json I'm sending.

Comment: You ISO date should be complete: ISODate("2017-07-17T08:06:02.041Z")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this given input:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596c6fea53cc7100104628fa"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-17T08:06:02.041Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596c7162973f33000fc8bb81"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-17T08:12:18.170Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596c736c15371f00106b9e3a"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-17T08:21:00.291Z")
}
```

This query:

`...find({"timestamp": {$gte: ISODate("2017-07-17T08:06:02.041Z"), $lte: ISODate("2017-07-17T08:12:18.170Z")}})`

Would return:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596c6fea53cc7100104628fa")
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-17T08:06:02.041Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596c7162973f33000fc8bb81"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-17T08:12:18.170Z")
}
```

Which is what you would expect, the results match to the dot the 2 borders. So in a nutshell it would be included if it is an `exact` match, otherwise you would get only the once in between.

Comment: yeah I see now, it's logical cos `ISODate("2021-07-27")` is actually equal to `ISODate("2021-07-27T00:00:00")` so apparently it won't find the tests done later, that's at `2021-07-27T12:17:57`. So yeah. Thank you a lot for the answer.

Comment: But is there any other way to "explain" to mongo that I want the right border to be included? I mean something apart from setting the time to `T23:59:59`. Cos it just looks terrible...I could just increment the day, for instance if I want my `date_to` to be `2018-07-08` I could just take it to be `2018-07-09` but it doesn't look great either.